# Python -- put wireless card in Monitor Mode without `subprocess` or `os.system`

Tags: python-2.7, wireless, scapy, nic, wifi

**OBJECTIVE**

Programatically put wireless card into Monitor mode **without** using `subprocess` or `os.system`

---

I am running Linux and I understand that I could

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

This could be done with `subprocess`, `os.system` or pause the program and use the shell.

I am using Python 2.7. It would be preferable if an answer includes a way to do this with Scapy, but I am unsure if this can be done without using a system call.

Comment: Use `strace` to see what syscalls are made by those programs, and then do the same.

Comment: Could you post your solution if you found any?

Comment: @phoebus Ended up using `subprocess`